# How to view logs of failed jobs with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've created a Kubernetes job that has now failed. Where can I find the logs to this job?

I'm not sure how to find the associated pod (I assume once the job fails it deletes the pod)?

Running `kubectl describe job` does not seem to show any relevant information:

```
Name:           app-raiden-migration-12-19-58-21-11-2018
Namespace:      localdev
Selector:       controller-uid=c2fd06be-ed87-11e8-8782-080027eeb8a0
Labels:         jobType=database-migration
Annotations:    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"batch/v1","kind":"Job","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"jobType":"database-migration"},"name":"app-raiden-migration-12-19-58-21-1...
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Wed, 21 Nov 2018 12:19:58 +0000
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 1 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=c2fd06be-ed87-11e8-8782-080027eeb8a0
           job-name=app-raiden-migration-12-19-58-21-11-2018
  Containers:
   app:
    Image:  pp3-raiden-app:latest
    Port:   <none>
    Command:
      php
      artisan
      migrate
    Environment:
      DB_HOST:        local-mysql
      DB_PORT:        3306
      DB_DATABASE:    raiden
      DB_USERNAME:    <set to the key 'username' in secret 'cloudsql-db-credentials'>  Optional: false
      DB_PASSWORD:    <set to the key 'password' in secret 'cloudsql-db-credentials'>  Optional: false
      LOG_CHANNEL:    stderr
      APP_NAME:       Laravel
      APP_KEY:        ABCDEF123ERD456EABCDEF123ERD456E
      APP_URL:        http://192.168.99.100
      OAUTH_PRIVATE:  <set to the key 'oauth_private.key' in secret 'laravel-oauth'>  Optional: false
      OAUTH_PUBLIC:   <set to the key 'oauth_public.key' in secret 'laravel-oauth'>   Optional: false
    Mounts:           <none>
  Volumes:            <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age   From            Message
  ----     ------                ----  ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      2m    job-controller  Created pod: app-raiden-migration-12-19-58-21-11-2018-pwnjn
  Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  2m    job-controller  Job has reach the specified backoff limit
```

Comment: It seems your pod hasn't started yet. It's failing to start.

Comment: From Kubernetes documentation: "Once .spec.backoffLimit has been reached the Job (restartPolicy=OnFailure) will be marked as failed and any running Pods will be terminated.". The pods would have been deleted in this case.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

One other approach:

- `kubectl describe job $JOB`
- Pod name is shown under "Events"
- `kubectl logs $POD`

Comment: If `activeDeadlineSeconds` is exceeded, then the pod is deleted and I could find no way to look at the logs. Events will say "<none>"

Comment: If you cannot find the pod name under "Events" it's probably because of `successfulJobsHistoryLimit: <num>` configuration within `CronJob`

Answer (score 42):

You can also execute

```
kubectl logs job.batch/your-job-name
```

In case you job has more than one pod, you will see a message similar to:

```
Found X pods, using pod/your-job-name-xxxxx
```

(Tested with kubectl version = 1.21.2)

Comment: By far the easiest answer for a batch job, since we do not have to look up the pods for a job

Comment: For me it returned 
error: timed out waiting for the condition

Comment: This should be the correct answer unless you have an older version of kubectl.

Answer (score 16):

Use this command to show all pods, even failed ones:

```
kubectl get pods -A
```

And then a pod will be shown like below:

```
app-raiden-migration-12-19-58-21-11-2018-pwnjn   0/1       Error     0          6m
```

Then use:

```
kubectl logs lighthouse-timer-1553800620-pwssv
```

Comment: Flag --show-all has been deprecated, will be removed in an upcoming release. Any idea what will be used to replace it?

Comment: -A just means all namespaces. It's not going to show the pods related to a failed job.

Comment: There is no such pod.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the pods of this job by running:

```
kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=app-raiden-migration-12-19-58-21-11-2018
```

but in this case i think you won't find any pods because no pod is created, and as mentioned in [this link: Job Termination and Cleanup](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup), pods are not deleted after jobs completion.
But still i don't know how you can find out why that pod failed to run (but if there is a pod and you could find it, you can find the logs of that pod). I had the same mistake and i ran the job again and job worked successfully.

EDIT:

I just see the events of your job, your job has made pod and you can see the logs of your pod by your pod name as I mentioned above.